# Facebook PHP API and token expiration

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have PHP site. User can come on that site and connect with Facebook. When user is connected I get user id and access token and store to database. I used that access token to post some things (text, photos, and links on users FB).

Now, I see that access token is expiring after 60 days (extended token) and after that I need to prompt user to connect to Facebook again.

Problem is that my site need to post couple of messages which user wrote after he pass. And user can connect to Facebook for example 1. Sep 2013 and can pass after couple of years.

Is there any way how can I post that messages on that user's Facebook account, without prompting user to connect to Facebook again (of course if user not deny app on Facebook account before that) even token is expired.

Twitter and YouTube has unexpiring tokens which allow me to post on that social networks posts in couple of years (of course if user not deny my app on theirs accounts on twitter and YouTube).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simply posting to the user's wall; you can use the **APP ACCESS TOKEN** (`APP-ID|APP-SECRET`) for that.

Comment: Is it possible to create album and upload photos to that album with that APP ACCESS TOKEN?

Comment: No. You can simply post and fetch the basic details, that's it. Else, you have to refresh the token by taking the user to the login flow again- as you know already